# PUT request to upload binary data with Apache Airflow's SimpleHttpOperator

Tags: python, rest, http, airflow

I'm trying to upload some binary data using Apache Airflow's [SimpleHttpOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/_api/airflow/providers/http/operators/http/index.html).
When using python's [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) I do this simply with

```py
requests.put(f'my.url.example',
              data=open('path_to_file, 'rb'), # parameter containing path to file
              auth=(username, password))
```

but with my Airflow's operator, the path to file is not correctly rendered when calling **open()**:

```py
put_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='put_task',
        http_conn_id='my_connection',
        endpoint="my.url.example/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_metadata', key='checksum') }}",
        method='PUT',
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data=open(templ_local_filepath, 'rb'),          # not correctly rendered
        do_xcom_push=True,
        log_response=True,
    )
```

How do you suggest me to proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I found was to do so through a `BashOperator` (which I also think is more performant).

```py
put_task = BashOperator(
            task_id='put_task_',
            bash_command=rest_operations.templated_put,
            env={
                'basepath': basepath,
                'filename': filename,
                'checksum': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_metadata', key='checksum') }}",
                'user': user,
                'password': password
            }
        )
```

whose bash command is

```sh
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" \
        -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \
        --upload-file $basepath/$filename \
        https://my.url.example/upload/data/$checksum \
        --user $user:$password
```